# Bash cron job on hpanel not locating directory

Tags: bash, cron

I have the following code on cron job, it runs but the code does not really do what it supposed to. It does not create the directory plus is does not do anything in the code. Please help check if the way I pointed to the directory is wrong.

```sh
#!/bin/bash 
NAMEDATE=`date +%F_%H-%M`_`whoami`
NAMEDATE2=`date ` 
mkdir ~/home/u3811*****/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE -m 0755 
mysqldump -u u3811*****_boss -p"*******" u3811*****_data | gzip ~/home/u3811*****/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE/db.sql.gz
echo "This is the database backup for website.com on $NAMEDATE2" |
mailx -a ~/home/u3811*****/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE/db.sql.gz -s "website.com Database attached" -- mail@gmail.com 
chmod -R 0644 ~/home/u3811*****/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE/*
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your NAMEDATE variable needs to be modified a bit, as shown below, for more information about variables in bash see this [link](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html)

```
NAMEDATE=$(date +%F_%H-%M"_"$(whoami))
```

When you issue the mkdir command you will need to pass the -p option to create the complete directory structure if it doesn't exists.

```
mkdir -p ~/home/u3811numbers/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE -m 0755
```

Also, the ~ character on Linux based distributions is used as a shortcut for the home directory of the user that invokes it so, in the line below the result is /home//home/u3811*****/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/2020-09-04_23-13_ you can read more about it in [here](https://fossbytes.com/home-directory-root-directory-symbols-forward-slash-tilde/)

In you last command before the exit, you might need to pass a wildcard (*) to avoid removing the executable bit on the directory, see below

```
chmod -R 0644 ~/home/u3811*****/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE/
```

The final version of your script will look something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

NAMEDATE=$(date +%F_%H-%M"_"$(whoami))

NAMEDATE2=date

mkdir -p ~/home/u3811******/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE -m 0755

mysqldump -u u3811*****_boss -p"******" u3811*****_data | gzip > ~/home/u3811*****/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE/db.sql.gz

echo "This is the database backup for website.com on $NAMEDATE2" | mailx -a ~/home/u3811*****/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE/db.sql.gz -s "website.com Database attached" -- mail@gmail.com

chmod -R 0644 ~/home/u3811*****/domains/website.com/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE/*
```

To debug a bash script you can always pass the -x flag for more information take a look at this [article](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)

Comment: thank you fot your time eorochena but the issue persists. The code i posted above works fine on cpanel but with directory format

mkdir -p ~/public_html/cron/backup/files/$NAMEDATE -m 0755

i don not know why the same dont work on hpanel thats why i decided to try using the full directory of the file

Comment: @fengxu is this what your are trying to do? https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-run-and-configure-cron-jobs-on-hpanel/

Comment: i have other php cron  jobs that aer working very fine, i know how to set a cron job on hostinger. My issue is the above bash script does work, the cron job executes but the script does not do what its supposed to do.

Comment: Have you tried running each individual statement in the script using the SSH Access feature?